# Declare a function separately for .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each

I would like to declare a function separately and use it for each loop on a class. The function simply assigns a serialized id to each element belonging to the same class. It works fine when function is declared and called like:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item-input").each(function (index,object){
    var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var new_id = current_id+index;
    $(this).attr('id',new_id);
  });
});
```

however, when i separate the function call from declaration. it doesn't work and raises an exception.

```
function id_serializer(i,obj){
  var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var new_id = current_id+i;
  $(this).attr('id',new_id);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item-input").each(id_serializer(i,obj));
});
```

It raises following exception:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: i is not defined ReferenceError: i is not defined
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

Need help please...

Comment: `$(".item-input").each(id_serializer);`

Comment: ```$(".item-input").each(function(i,obj){
id_serializer(i,obj)
});```

Comment: The redundant duplication there is redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item-input").each(id_serializer(i,obj)); // You are calling function inside .each
});
```

Update it as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item-input").each(id_serializer); // Just pass the callback function instead
});
```